# MakeFile add library

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, cmake, clion

I've installed the library via vcpkg and it gave me the next rows to add to cmake:

```
find_package(Libevent CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE libevent::core libevent::extra)
```

But my project uses Makefile instead of cmake. How can I add the library to project?

Makefile:

```
# Remove NDEBUG define to trigger asserts
CPPFLAGS+=-O2 -std=gnu++11 -I. -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DOPENSSL
LDFLAGS+=-levent -lstdc++ -lssl -lcrypto

uname_S := $(shell sh -c 'uname -s 2>/dev/null || echo not')
ifeq ($(uname_S),FreeBSD)
  CXX=clang++
  LIBEVENT_HOME=/usr/local
  CPPFLAGS+=-I${LIBEVENT_HOME}/include
  LDFLAGS+=-L${LIBEVENT_HOME}/lib
else
  CXX?=g++
endif

all: swift-dynamic

swift: swift.o sha1.o compat.o sendrecv.o send_control.o hashtree.o bin.o binmap.o channel.o transfer.o httpgw.o statsgw.o cmdgw.o avgspeed.o avail.o storage.o zerostate.o zerohashtree.o livehashtree.o live.o api.o content.o swarmmanager.o address.o livesig.o exttrack.o

swift-static: swift
    ${CXX} ${CPPFLAGS} -o swift *.o ${LDFLAGS} -static -lrt
    strip swift
    touch swift-static

swift-dynamic: swift
    ${CXX} ${CPPFLAGS} -o swift *.o ${LDFLAGS}
    touch swift-dynamic

clean:
    rm -f *.o swift swift-static swift-dynamic 2>/dev/null

.PHONY: all clean swift swift-static swift-dynamic
```

Comment: Showing your Makefile would be a way more helpful.

Comment: @bloody added my makefile

Comment: Shouldn't be `-llibevent` added to `LDFLAGS` then?

Comment: What's the actual library name that cmake targets `libevent::core` and `libevent::extra` refers to? Also something not quite irrelevant, do you have any reason against using cmake to build your project?